# Excel VBA run time error 13 with Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I have some nested `Select Case` code which works when I choose main case 2, 3, 4 or 5  (I get the nested case options for each), but when I choose `Case 1` I get a run time error 13 which ignores the input box defining the options.

I have looked at this a hundred times and cannot see where my error is, there has to be one somewhere and wondered if anyone can see what is missing or wrong here, this is the part of my code which throws the error.

```vb
Variants:

Sizes = Application.InputBox("Which EMS 066 option do you wish to load & check against" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & "1. S690 All variants & sizes" & vbLf & vbLf & "2. S890 All variants & sizes" & vbLf & vbLf & "3. S960 All variants & sizes" & vbLf & vbLf & "4. S650MC-D All sizes" & vbLf & vbLf & "5. S700MC-D All sizes" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf, "Select which option to load")

If Sizes = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Select Case Sizes
        Case 1
            ws.Activate
            Ans = MsgBox("You have selected S690 variant?", vbYesNo) ' allows a loop if you have made a mistake and will take you back to the selection option
            If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Variants Else
                Option1 = Application.InputBox("Please define the specific type and size of S690 you require to check against" & vbLf & vbLf & "1. S690Q 3mm to 50mm" & vbLf & "2. S690Q 50 to 100mm" & vbLf & "3. S690Q100 to 150mm" & vbLf & vbLf & "4. S690QL 3 to 50mm" & vbLf & vbLf & "5. S690QL 50 to 100mm" & vbLf & vbLf & "6. S690QL 100 to 150mm" & vbLf & vbLf & "7. S690QL1 3 to 50mm" & vbLf & vbLf & "8. S690QL1 50 to 100mm" & vbLf & vbLf & "9. S690QL1 100 to 150mm" & vbLf & vbLf, "Plese select the Option from the Drawing")

                Select Case Option1
                    Case 1
                        Ans = MsgBox("You have selected S690Q between 3 and 50mm is this correct?", vbYesNo) ' allows a loop if you have made a mistake and will take you back to the selection option
                        If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Variants Else:
                            rng2.Copy: rng1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                              :=False, Transpose:=False
                            rng4.Copy: rng3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                              :=False, Transpose:=False
                            rng6.Copy: rng5.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                              :=False, Transpose:=False
```

This has been driving me nuts for a whole day and cannot for the life of me see what is wrong, I have even copied the code from the second main `Case Select` and tried it unedited and edited and I get the same error.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: You appear to think that code after the `If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Variants Else` executes in the `Else` branch. It does not; the `If` has an empty `Else` branch that does nothing, and the following code executes always. Same for `If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Variants Else:`. Which looks like it works for you because your `If` branch is a Goto which prevents it from going to the next line. That is *not* a good use of `GoTo`. You can make if much less confusing by removing the `Else` altogether.

Comment: PEH when I select the first case (case 1) my code seems to skip the option 1 input box and throws the error at the first nested case

Comment: Have you tried `If Ans = vbNo Then: GoTo Variants: Else`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompt of the input box may have a maximum of 255 characters. If it has more, you get error 2015. If you come to your second `Select Case`, you compare the error to `1` and get the error 13.

So: shorten your prompt in case 1 and you are fine :)

Comment: Absolutely spot on, thank you - i really didn't know there was a character limit with this code.

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help! In such cases debugging line for line and checking status of every variable helps a lot. Happy coding :)